# List<Object> inline initialisation order not maintained

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am using this LINQ to Entities statement to select some vales from a db :

```
dbContext
  .dbSet.Where(e => e.FILLDATE.Equals(tradingDate))
  .Select(e => new List<Object> { 
     e.string1, 
     e.string2, 
     e.string3, 
     e.int1.ToString(), 
     e.string5, 
     e.decimal1.ToString(), 
     e.decimal2.ToString() 
   })
  .ToList();
```

When I am trying to read values from `List<List<Object>>`, the order of elements in every other item (`List<Object>`) is reversed. All odd indices have reversed order.

This is what I'm getting..

`[ string1, string2, string3, in1, string5, decimal1, decimal2 ]`

`[ decimal2, decimal1, string5, in1, string3, string2, string1 ]`

`[ string1, string2, string3, in1, string5, decimal1, decimal2 ]`

`[ decimal2, decimal1, string5, in1, string3, string2, string1 ]`

`and so on..`

I can't seem to figure out why is this happening.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe data was inserted in list in wrong order.  Your code to remove look fine.

Comment: The initialization order is mentioned int the question, but how is the order getting messed up internally and that too in a neat manner. Only odd indices have the reverse ordered List and the order is exact reverse..

Comment: As I said you read code is correct.  The initialization code must be wrong.

Comment: I am reading the data from a database, the data is solid in the db.

Comment: Entity uses an EDMX mapping file to link the database tables/columns.  If the database is correct then there is something wrong with the mapping.  But doesn't make sense and only odd rows would be backwards unless the mapping table changed between the reading and writing.  What would happen if the even rows were written to the database and then the edmx file was changed and then odd rows were saved?  But that wouldn't explain the database being correct.  I would look at the edmx file to see if it looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why you get this result but it is likely down to the `Select` expression running as part of the query i.e. it is running on your database, not in-process. SQL queries do not respect ordering unless they have an `ORDER BY` clause.

To run the `Select` method in-process and respect ordering, add `AsEnumerable()` into your statement. This forces the statement to use the `Enumerable.Select` extension method, not `Queryable.Select`.

```
dbContext
  .dbSet.Where(e => e.FILLDATE.Equals(tradingDate))
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(e => new List<Object> { ... } );
```

Comment: But I still do not quite get the explanation. `ORDER BY` is for ordering of the rows in the result dataset. But how come the order of columns is altering at each iteration over the rows?

Comment: It will be running a sub-select statement to get the columns. I think you're best off looking at the SQL generated by the statement, e.g. by running it in LinqPad, then you'll be able to see why this was caused.